# Encryption and Decryption in C# using MD5CryptoServiceProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography

I have a service named CryptoService which inherit the interface ICryptoService that consist of 2 method Crypto Decrypto function.

Encryption of a string is Working but the  Decryption of hash result will return my key instead of the Decrypted string.

Here is my encryption code :

```
private string _salt = "*1234567890!@#$%^&*()14344*";        
private string Crypto(string text)
        {
            var hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] toEncryptArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt);

            byte[] keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt));
            hashmd5.Clear();

            TripleDesProvider.Key = keyArray;
            TripleDesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TripleDesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            ICryptoTransform cTransform = TripleDesProvider.CreateEncryptor();

            byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);
        }
```

My decryption code :

```
private string Decrypto(string text)
        {
            try
            {

                var hashmd5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
                byte[] toEncryptArray = Convert.FromBase64String(text);

                byte[] keyArray = hashmd5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_salt));

                hashmd5.Clear();

                TripleDesProvider.Key = keyArray;
                TripleDesProvider.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
                TripleDesProvider.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

                ICryptoTransform cTransform = TripleDesProvider.CreateDecryptor();
                byte[] resultArray = cTransform.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

                TripleDesProvider.Clear();

                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
                //return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray);
            }
            catch
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```

provided here the screenshot in action.

[image]

here are the references of my codes I found in the internet 
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14150/Encrypt-and-Decrypt-Data-with-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `toEncryptArray` in Encrypto gets the value `_salt`. You meant `text`.

So, good news, your decryption works.

Comment: I didn't notice that. The one that i'm encrypting is my salt value. So basically, Encryption and Decryption works. 
I just didn't use my parameter in Encryption. 


Thank you for pointing that out. Really appreciate,

Answer (score 2):

This cannot work.  A hash, such as MD5, is one-way.  You cannot get the original text from the hash value.

If your crypto service runs on the same machine, I suggest using the [Data Protection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get the original text from the hash value, you cannot decrypt it?

It was just the same implementation on my references but on that it decrypt the hash value ..
check the link i posted.

BTW, Thank you for your response.

Comment: The hash is being used to generate the key, not to encrypt the data.